# How to post a request to azure ML web service using angular js?

Tags: angularjs, azure

I am trying to build an UI for azure ML model using angular js. I designed an HTML page where user input is captured using ng-model The issue am facing now in this effort is, getting 400 Bad request error as azure expects to send a data in POST request in below mentioned format. I get 200 success message when I test this sample value in Post Request. How should I send a user input for values in POST request. Appreciate any help.

Azure's expected Request body sample:

```
{

 "Inputs": {

    "input1": {
      "ColumnNames": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3"       
      ],
      "Values": [
        [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "GlobalParameters": {}
}
```

My Test javascript is

```
$http ({

          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'url',
          data    : '{"Inputs": {"input1": {"ColumnNames": ["col1","col2","col3"],"Values": ["value1","value2","value3"]]}}}',

          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json',                    
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer apikey'
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a mistake in the angularjs application, when you are generating the data payload.

In the sample,

```
"Values": [
        [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
        ]
      ]
```

the `value` is a nested array.

However in your fronted code snippet:

```
{"Inputs": {"input1": {"ColumnNames": ["col1","col2","col3"],"Values": ["value1","value2","value3"]]}}}
```

which is an invaild json object. (missing a `[` behide `"Values"`).

I suggest you can generate an object as the Request body sample shows, and set id object directly in `$http`'s post body payload, instead of writing a json string it manually.